# BLE Range Calculation

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

My bluetooth chip (SOC) has tx power of -6 to +8dbm and receive sensitivity of -93dbm. But my chipset manufacturer is saying max range possible is 40-50 meters only. Why is this the case? I thought BLE devices were capable of up to 100 meters. What else can I improve in the circuit to increase the range? Appreciate your help.

Comment: 100m: theoretical distance (not reality), with no wall, not disturbance, no reflexion etc.

Comment: Hello Larme, Yes, I understand 100meters in theoretical. But as per my manufacturer, even 50meters itself is theoretical with this chipset. So in reality, I will get much less depending on noise etc. My question is how can I increase the theoretical maximum with my chipset that has the above TX power and RX sensitivity.

Comment: Have you tried out the range yourself out in an open field?

Comment: @Emil, unfortunately, I have not received it here yet. It is still with the manufacturer at the assembly stage.